# should i remove mysql_error function from project?

Tags: php, mysql, security

is it **unsecure** using.

```
mysql_error();
```

function in a site when programming is finished?

I have used this code all over my project

```
mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
```

users can see database errors.

should i remove mysql_error function from my project?

or there is a way to **hide happening errors**?

Comment: If possible, you shouldn't even be using the `mysql_*` functions. Using PDO or mysqli (in object-oriented mode), it is very easy to write a wrapper that will handle errors exactly how you want, like sending you an email with a full stack trace instead of displaying the error back to the user (which is a bad idea security-wise).

Answer (score 1):

`or die(...)` is really an ugly quick shot "error handling" method. `mysql_error` isn't really the issue, `die` is. The closest replacement for it without rewriting your entire error handling infrastructure and a good idea in general are exceptions:

```
throw new Exception(mysql_error());
```

You have a lot of flexibility how you want to handle those. In production you'd set your global exception handler to log all uncaught exceptions but not output their message to screen.